# gitingnore isn't ignoring my node_modules folder. Though .env file is ignored

Tags: git, gitignore

My gitignore file is not ignoring the node_modules folder. This causing the folder is uploaded in github.

I have attached some commands that are included in the screenshot.

[This is the screenshot of my folder directory and code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uq1fk.png)

Comment: might be typo make sure that it is /node_modules in .gitignore or provide minimal repository to reproduce it via github

Comment: If you spelt  node_modules correctly in the .gitignore file, it might be that you initially had committed the code to git.
You first need to remove it from git then make a new commit with node_modules added in the .gitignore file.

To remove the already tracked file, do:

'git rm -rf --cached node_modules'

Then commit your new changes, then node_modules will be ignored.